# How to correctly refresh SDL2 window after resizing

Tags: c, sdl-2

I wrote a little SDL2 app that reacts on resizing by rearranging its contents. It works quite nice on Windows 10, but not on my Linux machine.

Here's the MCVE that (hopefully) reproduces the problem:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

    SDL_Window *w = SDL_CreateWindow("MCVE",
            SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 250, 250,
            SDL_WINDOW_ALLOW_HIGHDPI|SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);

    SDL_Renderer *r = SDL_CreateRenderer(w, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);

    SDL_Surface *shape = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(0, 500, 500, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    SDL_Rect rect = { .x = 100, .y = 100, .h = 300, .w = 300 };
    SDL_FillRect(shape, &rect, SDL_MapRGB(shape->format, 0xff, 0, 0));
    SDL_Texture *t = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(r, shape);
    SDL_RenderClear(r);
    SDL_RenderCopy(r, t, 0, 0);
    SDL_RenderPresent(r);

    SDL_Event ev;
    while (SDL_WaitEvent(&ev))
    {
        switch (ev.type)
        {
        case SDL_QUIT:
            SDL_Quit();
            return 0;
        case SDL_WINDOWEVENT:
            if (ev.window.event == SDL_WINDOWEVENT_SIZE_CHANGED)
            {
                SDL_RenderClear(r);
                SDL_RenderCopy(r, t, 0, 0);
                SDL_RenderPresent(r);
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

compile command:

```
gcc -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -pedantic -osdlresize sdlresize.c -lSDL2main -lSDL2
```

Note any error checking and cleanup is skipped just for brevity, the [real code is here](https://github.com/Zirias/bigfingers) for reference.

What I get on my Linux machine when resizing the window often looks like this:

[image: screenshot of resized window]

In case you can't see the image: the content isn't properly refreshed, it shows some area to the right and the bottom with contents of whatever is *below* my window on the desktop.

Is there anything wrong in my handling of the `SDL_WINDOWEVENT_SIZE_CHANGED`? The same thing happens if I handle `SDL_WINDOWEVENT_RESIZED` instead...

Comment: It may be due to combination of double buffering and compositing window manager. I think first and foremost you should redraw on SDL_WINDOWEVENT_EXPOSED.

Comment: @keltar works perfectly, thanks! In the real app, I moved drawing to EXPOSED and only kept the calculations for the new size in SIZE_CHANGED. Do you have any explanation why my broken approach worked on windows? Anyhow, I'd be happy to accept this solution as an answer!

Comment: This problem pops now and then, and as far as I remember, it happens on windows with aero enabled too. I persoanally don't use compositing window managers so this doesn't occur to me. As SDL often used for games with very dynamic content, most common approach is to redraw unconditionally.

Comment: @keltar Would you like to give an answer? As already stated, your comments solved my problem, thanks!